# Apply a function to all coefficients of a polynomial

Tags: functions, replacement, polynomials

I would like to apply a given function $f$ to each one of the coefficients of a polynomial.

For example if $P=(x - 2) (y^2 + 1)= -2 + x - 2 y^2 + x y^2$ and $f(c)=c^2$, I would like to obtain the polynomial $Q= 4+x+4y^2 + xy^2$.

I am aware of `CoefficientRules` and `FromCoefficientRules` but I do not know how to modify rules.

```
f[t_] := t^2;
P = (x - 2) (y^2 + 1);
P // Expand
(* -2 + x - 2 y^2 + x y^2 *)
rules = CoefficientRules[P, {x, y}]
(* {{1, 2} -> 1, {1, 0} -> 1, {0, 2} -> -2, {0, 0} -> -2}*)
(* Something should happen here I guess *)
Q = FromCoefficientRules[rules, {x, y}]
(* -2 + x - 2 y^2 + x y^2 *)
```

Ideally the method could also apply to more general function, such as going from $2 \sin(2x) -5$ to $4\sin(x) + 25$, although it may be more involved as $\sin(2x)$ could also be changed into $\sin(4x)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
rules = CoefficientRules[P, {x, y}]
newrules = MapAt[f, #, 2] & /@ rules
FromCoefficientRules[newrules, {x, y}]
```

Or, in general,

```
CoefficientMap[f_, P_] := FromCoefficientRules[
   MapAt[f, #, 2] & /@ CoefficientRules[P, Variables[P]], Variables[P]]

CoefficientMap[f_, P_, vars_] := FromCoefficientRules[
   MapAt[f, #, 2] & /@ CoefficientRules[P, vars], vars]
```

In general, if you replace `MapAt[f, #, 2] &` with a function which takes `Rule[powerlist, coeff]` to `Rule[newpowerlist, newcoeff]`, you could build more general maps on polynomials! (Currently, `MapAt[f, #, 2] &[Rule[p, c]]` yields `Rule[p, f[c]]`.)

For the application you mention later on, though, where you change `Sin[2 x]` to `Sin[4 x]` it sounds like you might want to build your own version of `Variables` or `CoefficientRules` for that situation which would extract and encode Fourier coefficients of finite Fourier series (or something like that)—possibly by converting them into polynomial variables in their own right.