# How to apply a function to coefficients of a polynomial?

Tags: polynomials

I found [Apply a function to all coefficients of a polynomial](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/244857/apply-a-function-to-all-coefficients-of-a-polynomial) but I could not understand

I want to apply `Round` to the coeffricients of $x^2 + 3.1x^3 + 5.4x^4$. The `Map` function tries to Round the entire expression like `3.1x^3`

Comment: Try:  `x^2 + 3.1 x^3 + 5.4 x^4 /. x_?NumericQ :> Round[x]`   This results in:  `x^2 + 3 x^3 + 5 x^4`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use 3-arg [`Collect`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Collect) for this purpose:

```
Collect[x^2+3.1 x^3+5.4 x^4, x, Round]
```

> x^2 + 3 x^3 + 5 x^4

Comment: Note that if there is a variable in any of the coefficients, this does not behave as expected, e.g., `Collect[a*x^2 + 3.1 x^3 + 5.4 x^4, x, Round]`

Comment: Why I cannot turn this into a function? `polyRound[poly0_] := Collect[poly0_, x, Round]` gives `Round[Pattern[
2
x
+1.5
3
x
,_]]
`

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear[x, expr]
expr = x^2 + 3.1 x^3 + 5.4 x^4;
crules = Merge[CoefficientRules[expr], Round @@ # &] // Normal

FromCoefficientRules[crules, Variables[expr]]
```

> x^2 + 3 x^3 + 5 x^4